# Installing OroCRM on Windows

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-2.1, orocrm

***When I try to install OroCrm on linux and in an Macintosh (Mac OS X) it was successfully. But not for Windows OS. Rather going to Bitnami OroCRM Installer I especially prefer to install seperately from Apache 2.4.x, PHP 7.1.x, MySQL like in an *nix OS***.

After completing the Pre-requisite steps, from the browser

- I navigated to the URL http://orocrm.example.com/install.php and by clicking Next
  Button
- The above URL has redirecting to the page http://orocrm.example.com/installer . Here I could just see the blank
  page.

So I tried to install via command Line Interface:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\orocrm>php composer.phar install

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Package operations: 0 installs, 1 update, 0 removals
  - Updating sebastian/phpcpd dev-master (cff7f36 => b6dd25b):     Update failed (The .git directory is missing from C:\Apache24\htdocs\orocrm\vendor/sebastian/phpcpd, see https://getcomposer.org/commit-deps for more information)
    Would you like to try reinstalling the package instead [yes]? yes
  - Removing sebastian/phpcpd (dev-master)
  - Installing sebastian/phpcpd (dev-master b6dd25b): Cloning b6dd25b89f from cache
Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.
Generating autoload files
> ComponentInstaller\Installer::postAutoloadDump
Compiling component files
> Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
> Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile
> Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::setPermissions
> Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets
> Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::setAssetsVersion
Updating the "assets_version" parameter
```

I tried to create Database from the default parameters.yml file

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\orocrm>php app/console doctrine:database:create
Created database `oro_crm` for connection named default
```

Next in the Installation process:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\orocrm>php app/console oro:install
Installing Oro Application.

Oro requirements check:
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Mandatory requirements                                                                   |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | Vendor libraries must be installed                                                       |
| OK      | app/cache/ or var/cache/ directory must be writable                                      |
| OK      | app/logs/ or var/logs/ directory must be writable                                        |
| OK      | Configured default timezone "Asia/Kolkata" must be supported by your installation of PHP |
| OK      | iconv() must be available                                                                |
| OK      | json_encode() must be available                                                          |
| OK      | session_start() must be available                                                        |
| OK      | ctype_alpha() must be available                                                          |
| OK      | token_get_all() must be available                                                        |
| OK      | simplexml_import_dom() must be available                                                 |
| OK      | PCRE extension must be available                                                         |
| OK      | C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp (sys_get_temp_dir()) directory must be writable         |
+---------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| Check   | PHP settings                               |
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
| OK      | detect_unicode must be disabled in php.ini |
| OK      | string functions should not be overloaded  |
| OK      | memory_limit should be at least 512M       |
+---------+--------------------------------------------+
+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Oro specific requirements                          |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | PHP version must be at least 7.0 (7.1.7 installed) |
| OK      | GD extension must be at least 2.0                  |
| OK      | cURL extension must be at least 7.0                |
| OK      | mcrypt_encrypt() should be available               |
| OK      | intl extension should be available                 |
| OK      | icu library must be at least 3.8                   |
| OK      | zip extension should be installed                  |
| OK      | web/uploads/ directory must be writable            |
| OK      | web/media/ directory must be writable              |
| OK      | web/bundles/ directory must be writable            |
| OK      | app/attachment/ directory must be writable         |
| OK      | app/import_export/ directory must be writable      |
| OK      | web directory must be writable                     |
| OK      | app/config/parameters.yml file must be writable    |
+---------+----------------------------------------------------+
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Check   | Optional recommendations                                                                                                 |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| OK      | Vendors should be installed in order to check all requirements.                                                          |
| OK      | Requirements file should be up-to-date                                                                                   |
| OK      | PCRE extension should be at least version 8.0 (8.38 installed)                                                           |
| OK      | PHP-DOM and PHP-XML modules should be installed                                                                          |
| OK      | mb_strlen() should be available                                                                                          |
| OK      | utf8_decode() should be available                                                                                        |
| OK      | filter_var() should be available                                                                                         |
| OK      | intl extension should be available                                                                                       |
| OK      | intl extension should be correctly configured                                                                            |
| OK      | intl ICU version should be at least 4+                                                                                   |
| OK      | intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (57.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1) |
| OK      | intl ICU version installed on your system (57.1) does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)                 |
| OK      | intl.error_level should be 0 in php.ini                                                                                  |
| OK      | a PHP accelerator should be installed                                                                                    |
| OK      | realpath_cache_size should be at least 5M in php.ini                                                                     |
| OK      | short_open_tag should be disabled in php.ini                                                                             |
| OK      | magic_quotes_gpc should be disabled in php.ini                                                                           |
| OK      | register_globals should be disabled in php.ini                                                                           |
| OK      | session.auto_start should be disabled in php.ini                                                                         |
| OK      | PDO should be installed                                                                                                  |
| OK      | PDO should have some drivers installed (currently available: mysql)                                                      |
| OK      | SOAP extension should be installed (API calls)                                                                           |
| OK      | Tidy extension should be installed to make sure that any HTML is correctly converted into a text representation.         |
| OK      | finfo_open() should be available                                                                                         |
| OK      | COM extension should be installed                                                                                        |
| OK      | A JS Engine (node) is installed                                                                                          |
+---------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Setting up database.
Process migrations...
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migration\LoadEntityConfigStateMigration
  > Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\Migration\CreateMigrationTableMigration
  > Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroPlatformBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\ScopeBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroScopeBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\OrganizationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroOrganizationBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroSecurityBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroAttachmentBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\OroMessageQueueBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroMessageQueueBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\EmailBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEmailBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\CronBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroCronBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroUserBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\DataGridBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroDataGridBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\SSOBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroSSOBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\TranslationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroTranslationBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEntityBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\LocaleBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroLocaleBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEntityConfigBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroEntityExtendBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\IntegrationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroIntegrationBundleInstaller
  > Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroNotificationBundleInstaller
```

After finishing the installation. I tried to run the below command to warm-up the API documentation cache

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\orocrm>php app/console oro:api:doc:cache:clear

 // Warming up cache for the default view...

 // Warming up cache for the rest_json_api view...



  [Oro\Component\ChainProcessor\Exception\ExecutionFailedException]
  Processor failed: "oro_api.collect_subresources.initialize_subresources". Reason: Processor failed: "oro_api.get_co
  nfig.complete_definition". Reason: Entity "Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\Attachment" is not configurable



  [Oro\Component\ChainProcessor\Exception\ExecutionFailedException]
  Processor failed: "oro_api.get_config.complete_definition". Reason: Entity "Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\Atta
  chment" is not configurable



  [Oro\Bundle\EntityConfigBundle\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Entity "Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\Attachment" is not configurable


oro:api:doc:cache:clear [--view [VIEW]] [--no-warmup] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-s|--shell] [--process-isolation] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--current-user CURRENT-USER] [--current-organization CURRENT-ORGANIZATION] [--disabled-listeners DISABLED-LISTENERS] [--] <command>
```

**From dev.log file**

```
php.INFO: "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper" is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. Use "Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper" instead. {"type":16384,"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\HelperSet.php","line":86,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\HelperSet.php","line":86,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Command\\InstallCommand.php","line":88,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Helper\\HelperSet","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Oro\\Bundle\\InstallerBundle\\Command\\InstallCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":866,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":193,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":124,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\console","line":22,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
doctrine.DEBUG: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id_1, t0.class_name AS class_name_2, t0.created AS created_3, t0.updated AS updated_4, t0.mode AS mode_5, t0.data AS data_6 FROM oro_entity_config t0 [] []
php.INFO: The "oro_locale.twig.date_time_organization" service is deprecated since 1.11, will be removed after 1.13. {"type":16384,"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":67327,"level":28928,"stack":[{"function":"handleError","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\ErrorHandler","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":67327,"function":"trigger_error"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container.php","line":314,"function":"getOroLocale_Twig_DateTimeOrganizationService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":61411,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container.php","line":314,"function":"getTwigService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\cache\\dev\\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php","line":61765,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container.php","line":314,"function":"getWebProfiler_Controller_ProfilerService","class":"appDevDebugProjectContainer","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\nelmio\\api-doc-bundle\\Nelmio\\ApiDocBundle\\Extractor\\ApiDocExtractor.php","line":226,"function":"get","class":"Symfony\\Component\\DependencyInjection\\Container","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\nelmio\\api-doc-bundle\\Nelmio\\ApiDocBundle\\Extractor\\CachingApiDocExtractor.php","line":79,"function":"getReflectionMethod","class":"Nelmio\\ApiDocBundle\\Extractor\\ApiDocExtractor","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\ApiDoc\\CachingApiDocExtractor.php","line":97,"function":"all","class":"Nelmio\\ApiDocBundle\\Extractor\\CachingApiDocExtractor","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\ApiDoc\\CachingApiDocExtractor.php","line":135,"function":"all","class":"Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\ApiDoc\\CachingApiDocExtractor","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\Command\\DocCacheClearCommand.php","line":96,"function":"warmUp","class":"Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\ApiDoc\\CachingApiDocExtractor","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command.php","line":259,"function":"execute","class":"Oro\\Bundle\\ApiBundle\\Command\\DocCacheClearCommand","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":866,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":193,"function":"doRunCommand","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application.php","line":92,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application.php","line":124,"function":"doRun","class":"Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Console\\Application","type":"->"},{"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\app\\console","line":22,"function":"run","class":"Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Application","type":"->"}]} []
php.INFO: The "_method" requirement is deprecated since version 2.2 and will be removed in 3.0. Use the setMethods() method instead. {"type":16384,"file":"C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\symfony\\symfony\\src\\Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Route.php","line":652,"level":28928} []
console.ERROR: An error occurred while running command ""oro:api:doc:cache:clear"". Processor failed: "oro_api.collect_subresources.initialize_subresources". Reason: Processor failed: "oro_api.get_config.complete_definition". Reason: Entity "Oro\Bundle\AttachmentBundle\Entity\Attachment" is not configurable {"exit_code":0,"exception":"[object] (Oro\\Component\\ChainProcessor\\Exception\\ExecutionFailedException(code: 0): Processor failed: \"oro_api.collect_subresources.initialize_subresources\". Reason: Processor failed: \"oro_api.get_config.complete_definition\". Reason: Entity \"Oro\\Bundle\\AttachmentBundle\\Entity\\Attachment\" is not configurable at C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Component\\ChainProcessor\\ChainProcessor.php:44, Oro\\Component\\ChainProcessor\\Exception\\ExecutionFailedException(code: 0): Processor failed: \"oro_api.get_config.complete_definition\". Reason: Entity \"Oro\\Bundle\\AttachmentBundle\\Entity\\Attachment\" is not configurable at C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Component\\ChainProcessor\\ChainProcessor.php:44, Oro\\Bundle\\EntityConfigBundle\\Exception\\RuntimeException(code: 0): Entity \"Oro\\Bundle\\AttachmentBundle\\Entity\\Attachment\" is not configurable at C:\\Apache24\\htdocs\\orocrm\\vendor\\oro\\platform\\src\\Oro\\Bundle\\EntityConfigBundle\\Config\\ConfigManager.php:278)","arguments":{"command":"oro:api:doc:cache:clear"}} []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.exception" to listener "Oro\Bundle\LoggerBundle\EventSubscriber\ConsoleCommandSubscriber::onConsoleException". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\Console\DriverLockCommandListener::afterExecute". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Log\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

***At the End I tried to navigat to http://orocrm.example.com 

    Resulted in Blank Page***

---

*After Clearing & Warming up an entity config cache said by **Thomas P**,*
and from the **dev.log** file:

```
console.INFO: Launched command "oro:entity-config:cache:clear" {"arguments":{"command":"oro:entity-config:cache:clear"}} []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Log\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ConsoleContextListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\ApiBundle\EventListener\DumpApiDocConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\CacheBundle\EventListener\CacheWarmerListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\Console\OptionalListenersListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\FeatureToggleBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Event\JsRoutingDumpListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\LocaleBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\LoggerBundle\EventSubscriber\ConsoleCommandSubscriber::onConsoleCommand". [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\Console\DriverLockCommandListener::afterExecute". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Log\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
console.INFO: Launched command "oro:entity-config:cache:warmup" {"arguments":{"command":"oro:entity-config:cache:warmup"}} []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DebugHandlersListener::configure". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\EntityExtendBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Log\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\SecurityBundle\EventListener\ConsoleContextListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\ApiBundle\EventListener\DumpApiDocConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\CacheBundle\EventListener\CacheWarmerListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\Console\OptionalListenersListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MigrationBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\FeatureToggleBundle\EventListener\ConsoleCommandListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\NavigationBundle\Event\JsRoutingDumpListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\LocaleBundle\EventListener\LocaleListener::onConsoleCommand". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.command" to listener "Oro\Bundle\LoggerBundle\EventSubscriber\ConsoleCommandSubscriber::onConsoleCommand". [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE' [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\PlatformBundle\EventListener\Console\DriverLockCommandListener::afterExecute". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate". [] []
event.DEBUG: Notified event "console.terminate" to listener "Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\Log\Handler\ConsoleHandler::onTerminate". [] []
```

Comment: Hello bro, Did you installed OROCRM in windows? @Nishanth ॐ

Comment: Yep, I had tried but it failed. After that, I had migrated to *nix @Gem

Comment: I just new about this topic, may i know what is *nix, and how can i use it into windows?

Comment: It's a Linux OS or else you can go for bitnami's product for windows @Gem

Comment: Can i get Bitnami's product?

Comment: Issue solved after installing and downloading Bitnami OROCRM.

Comment: Can you just point out my error, My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the entity config cache regenerated properly. Remove all cache files and try these commands:

`oro:entity-config:cache:clear                     Clears the entity config cache.
oro:entity-config:cache:warmup                    Warms up the entity config cache.`

If no success, let us know which version of CRM you're installing and include full install log.

Comment: As I'm using  2.6.0. version of OroCRM. For install log refer the above updated post. Thanking You..

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on windows, and on unix system. Its slow database performance and hardcoded timelimit inside orocrm.

Your installation is not completed. As you can see, its stops without error after:
Oro\Bundle\NotificationBundle\Migrations\Schema\OroNotificationBundleInstaller
Its not last part of installation. I had bad dreams about this problem ;) there is nothing inside app logs, system logs, nothing.

The reason is that your reached time limit of database migration.
After investigate install script, it runs:

```
oro:migration:load
```

with default params:

```
$commandExecutor
    ->runCommand(
        'oro:migration:load',
        [
            '--force'             => true,
            '--process-isolation' => true,
            '--timeout'           => $commandExecutor->getDefaultOption('process-timeout'),
        ]
    )
```

Default value for process-timeout is inside:
Oro\Bundle\InstallerBundle\CommandExecutor
and value is 300. Not so much if you use database on hdd drive. I dont know if you can pass additional parameter with --timeout option for installer (you can try that), but you can change core value for a installation moment on windows. But working with orocrm on windows, with hdd drive is really hard.

So, just edit CommandExecutor for a moment, change:

```
const DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 300;
```

to some higher value, and you will be fine. Good luck (you will need it ;) )